# client connecting twice to server, Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, passport.socketio

I am trying to log username of logged in users by connecting socket.io to passport.js using passport.socketio. It is successful however it logs the username twice and after trying and searching for a fair amount of time I am stuck.

The code sections are as follows:

The Server Code:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
  cookieParser: cookieParser,       // the same middleware you registred in express
  key:          'connect.sid',       // the name of the cookie where express stores its session_id
  secret:       'hello',    // the session_secret to parse the cookie
  store:        new (require("connect-mongo")(Esession))({
    url: "mongodb://localhost/local"
  }),        // we NEED to use a sessionstore. no memorystore please
  success:      onAuthorizeSuccess,  // *optional* callback on success - read more below
  fail:         onAuthorizeFail,     // *optional* callback on fail/error - read more below
}));

function onAuthorizeSuccess(data, accept){
  console.log('successful connection to socket.io');
  accept(null, true);
  accept();
}

function onAuthorizeFail(data, message, error, accept){
  if(error)
    throw new Error(message);
  console.log('failed connection to socket.io:', message);

  // We use this callback to log all of our failed connections.
  accept(null, false);

  // OR

  // If you use socket.io@1.X the callback looks different
  // If you don't want to accept the connection
  if(error)
    accept(new Error(message));
  // this error will be sent to the user as a special error-package
  // see: http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket > error-object
}
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var userID = socket.request.user;
  console.log(userID.tg+ " has connected")

});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
server.listen(port);
```

The Client Code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect();
</script>
```

The output is as follows:

```
successful connection to socket.io
UserName has connected
UserName has connected
```

I am unsure as to why it is outputting twice any help would be much appreciated. I am relatively new to Node.js but I don't believe it's the passport part that is causing it, however I am stuck so I might not have the best idea.

Thanks in Advanced

EDIT:
Tried the latest version of socket and checked my own version both seem to be latest versions, Just to make sure I updated the client code to:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect();
</script>
```

the issue persists

Comment: https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem which I guess was my own stupidity,

I was accepting the connection twice upon successful authorization. Hence it was registering everything twice the correction should be:

```
function onAuthorizeSuccess(data, accept){
  console.log('successful connection to socket.io');
  //accept(null, true); -> remove this line
  accept();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This apparently was an error in previous version. You probably just need to upgrade. Check out the issue below.
https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/350

In the future, if you're trying to debug an issue like this it's useful to be acquainted with the [Node Events Class Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_listeners_event). `io` is just an event listener, and what's happening here is for *SOME* reason the `connection` event is doing double duty.

It's probably some **Socket.io** code that is firing `emit('connection')` one too many times.

When I'm debugging stuff like this, calling `emitter.listeners('event')` can be useful because it will tell me who, and more importantly how many listeners are listening.

So in your case, `io.listeners('connection');` will give you an array of everyone who's listening to that event. Obviously, `io` is registering it twice, but you can probably find out where with this trick.

Also, going into the package itself and grepping for `emit('connection');` will show you just where that nasty bug is.

Comment: I already had the latest version of socket and even tried to add it to client side to make sure (referring to the edit I made), also I tried to do `io.listeners('connection')` however it gave an error of: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` referring to listeners as the undefined function.

Comment: Aw yuck, that means there's an event listener in there somewhere, and they've mucked with the `on` method. I'd post in the issue with the version of Node, NPM, IO, and the OS you're on.

In the meantime, you can try digging through their source code and seeing what that `on` method really does.

Comment: @user2967697 your client library *is* out of date. The current version is *1.3.5*. What version is your server?

Comment: I just checked and it says that the server version it's 1.3.5.